# maven / m2e / gwt resources

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, m2e

how should we correctly handle resources - e.g. image files that must be used in a [ClientBundle](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#ImageResource)?

the maven way is to put the images somewhere unter `src/main/resources`. The m2e will add the `src/main/resources` folder as a source directory to the Eclipse project, but exclude all files in that folder. Which is the [intended behaviour](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ#Why_resource_folders_in_Java_project_have_excluded.3D.22.2A.22).

Now the problem is, that Eclipse will report an error on the `@Source()` annotation of the ClientBundle: which is also correct, because the images are excluded and thus not on the classpath.

note: if you remove the exclusion pattern from the resources folder as a workaround, then the eclipse build will work (but this is not desirable, because the maven filtering will then not work).

what is the clean solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the GPE? I thought this issue was fixed.

Comment: I think I have the latest version: _Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3 3.4.1.v201309130748-rel-r43_

Comment: When I change the maven-generated exclusion pattern from `**` to `**/*.*` (in the Eclipse Java Build Path) the error goes away. This should now also not collide with the maven builder.
But of course the problem is, that I must always change this manually after calling Maven - Update Project.
found a related bugreport: https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=122

Comment: since the original bugreport is already from 2010 I don't have the impression, this will ever be fixed. as a workaround, I've decided to use the maven-xmlmerger-plugin to automatically update my `.classpath` file accordingly in the maven `clean` phase. (after a `Maven`-`Update Project` call, I always recommend to `Project`-`Clean...` which will now run the xmlmerger plugin and thus update the `.classpath` file accordingly)